# Set Value on dijit/form/FilteringSelect after its already been created

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have  `FilteringSelect` using a `MemoryStore`. When a user types a value that is not in the store, they are prompted, asking if they would like to add the new value to the store. 
If they do, we call the server, create the new item, and on the response, we publish an event.

The topic subscriber is notified that a new item was created and added to the MemoryStore, which adds the option to the filteringselect.

At this point, the filtering select still has the same displayValue, and the option exists in the select. FilteringSelect.get("value") still returns "".

If you were to type a space, then hit backspace, (ending up with the same value), `FilteringSelect.get("value")` would return the correct item id.

`FilteringSelect.set("value", data[0].id)` doesn't do anything, no exception thrown, no affect.

Here's the code, contains some of the random calls I tried.

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/topic"],
  lang.hitch(this, function(Memory, array, topic) {
    this.liftStore = new Memory({
      data: []
    });
    array.forEach(data, lang.hitch(this, function(entry, i) {
      this.liftStore.data.push({
        name: entry.Name,
        id: entry.ID,
        identifier: entry.ID
      });
    }));
    this.lift.set("store", this.liftStore);
    topic.subscribe("LiftLog/NewLift", lang.hitch(this, function(data) {
      debugger;
      data[0].selected = true;
      data[0].identifier = data[0].id;
      this.liftStore.data.push(data[0]);
      this.lift.reset();
      this.lift.set("value", data[0].id);
      this.lift.set("value", data[0].id.toString());
   }));
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the item (i.e. `filteringSelect.set("item", newItem)` instead of setting the value? Note that you should give it the whole item, not just the id or the displayed value.

So, push the item into the store, and then set the item on the FilteringSelect:

```
this.liftStore.data.push(newItem);
this.lift.set("item", newItem);
```

Comment: Instead of using 'push' on data, prefer to use store.put(newItem). Because this is the better way to handle a store!